# Additional emails in Google Apps

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I want to create additional email addresses for my Google Apps account, like `support@mysite.com` or `press@mysite.com`.

Do I add additional users? Those emails addresses don't really represent users though.

Is there a different way of modeling that or should I just add more users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add unlimited alias email addresses to an existing account—Google calls them `Nicknames`.

1. Access the **Domain Management** for your domain (e.g. `https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/mysite.com/Dashboard`)
2. Click on **Organization & users**
3. Select the account you want to add an alias to
4. Find the **Nicknames** sections and click **Add a nickname**
5. All email sent to `newnickname@mysite.com` will be received by that account

Comment: You can also make one of your apps domain accounts a catch all address. Then you can give out email addresses that you make up and not have to worry about a corresponding nickname. This can make dealing with spam difficult, though, which is why I'm writing as a comment on @Shevek's better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The paid version of Google Apps implements shared mailboxes (poorly) through Google Groups. This would allow you to use a "support" account that would receive emails from outside users, and then display those messages in Google Groups. You can set security for your users to log into the board and reply to the messages as themselves or on behalf of the shared account. Any replies would be logged and so you can see both sides of the conversation. They also support digest emails, so supervisors can have a report of all the day's activity.

You can view more details on Google Apps on their hyper-technical getting started [guide](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=172473&topic=28068&ctx=topic), or focus on the shared mailbox feature [here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=167430)